# Can the load balancer replay a request to a different instance upon failure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb, system-design

There are multiple types of failures in an application:

- network
- machine
- database
- application

In case of application failure specifically, it is possible that a different server might be able to serve the request successfully. For instance, request to `a/` crashed the server but `b/` would work fine. But if request to B was directed to that particular server right after request to A, then it'd fail.

So given that, is it possible to have the load balancer try again with a different instance in case of error or time out.

I've confirmed ELB doesn't. But is there a load balancer that does?

Comment: *A* load balancer, or ELB specifically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS ELB - will it retry request if node fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31819162/aws-elb-will-it-retry-request-if-node-fails)

Comment: load balancer in general, And the question linked says ELB "will not be resent nor sent to another server."